# Android passing data from an activity to his fragment (viewpager)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, location, fragment

I have an ActionBar with Tabs which is fragments and ViewPager.
In the MainActivity there is implemented a LocationListener.

How can I passes the location data to the fragment from the MainActivity?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, LocationListener{

ActionBar actionbar;
ViewPager viewpager;
FragmentPageAdapter ft;
public String str="STRING";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    final RunFragment fragment = (RunFragment) ft.getItem(viewpager.getCurrentItem());
    fragment.setTv(str);

    actionbar = getActionBar();
    viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Run").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Map").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Statistics").setTabListener(this));
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


}
```

I want to write out the location data in the setTv() method the Tab's code:

```
public class RunFragment extends Fragment {

public TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_layout, container, false);
    tv =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    });


    return view;

}

public void setTv(String string){
    tv.setText(string);
}
```

}

Comment: [Check](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: You can attach a bundle, which will hold your data.

Comment: what problem you are getting? also call `fragment.setTv(str);` after setting adapter to ViewPager. i thing `onPageSelected` method is also called when first fragment is selected so use  `fragment.setTv(str);` in `onPageSelected` method

Comment: Yes but if I  do anything in the setTv() method the Android crashes, and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using an event bus library, like [Greenrobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). With it, you will be able to send out event objects from your activity whenever needed and the Fragment will receive them only when it is alive.

Comment: Thanks alot for this man!! Most clean and efficeint way of handling communication between activities and fragments with easy to implement documentation!! Upvote!!

Comment: If only the OP checked it out! I just used it now!

Answer (score 0):

u can do smthing like

```
// map is a GoogleMap object
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29)